# Adding components to a netbeans auto-generated java gui class

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I have a small MVC application I'm working on where the model supplies data which represents form components.  In this case, the controller populates the view with JButtons whose text is drawn from the model (a list of strings).

Unfortunately, I've grown attached to Netbeans' Gui Builder, so the form that the controller is populating is auto-generated.  Unfortunately, examination of the auto-generated form code tells me that I'm in for a lot of hassle to modify it at runtime.

At this point, I've not found much that addresses this issue.  I can build the form entirely in code, of course, but I'd prefer not to.  I can probably figure out how to hook into the auto-generated form's layout manager if that's the only real possibility (though a good example of how to go about that would be nice).

So, I guess my question is, is there a reasonable way to marry these two approaches?  Perhaps a custom generic container that can be added in the GUI and easily accessed from code?

Comment: Does "*the controller populates the view*" mean that the number, position, size, etc. of the buttons change, or is it only their text that is drawn from the model?

Comment: I mean that the view (the JFrame) is initially empty.  The controller adds JButtons directly based on the data found in the model.  It's not critical I implement it this way, but solving the general problem will certainly prove useful to me in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the best bet was to switch the frame layout to a specific type (like GridBag), and include the layout code in the controller when adding new components.  Not the best solution (I was hoping to manage as much as possible within the Gui Builder), but it seems to work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans does not require hard-coded values for Swing Controls' properties. You can always use custom code instead, to set the property values at runtime.

For example, here I have a JButton named 'copyButton' whose text is currently hard-coded to *Copy*.
[image: copyButton Properties]

However, by clicking the indicated ellipsis, it's possible to set the name using any code that returns a String.
[image: copyButton text property]

Comment: I did stumble upon that and marked it in my memory, but it addresses existing components only, so far as I can tell.  Any way to use that feature to trigger component generation at run-time?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to create hidden components in advance, and use the `setVisible` property to make it appear as if they are created at runtime. Beyond that, I guess look into the NetBeans source code and see how they do it.